# Question about Ricci Rotation Coeficients

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

Standard General Relativity calculations lies under, indeed, the calculations of three quantities: Christoffel Symbols of second kind, the components of Riemann tensor $R^{\mu}\hspace{1mm}_{\nu \gamma \delta}$ and the covariant derivative $\nabla _{\mu}$:

> The Christoffel Symbols are:
> $$ \Gamma ^{\mu}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu \gamma} =: \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\delta}\Big(\partial_{\nu} g_{\gamma \delta} + \partial_{\gamma} g_{\nu \delta} - \partial_{\delta} g_{\nu \gamma}\Big)$$
> The components of Riemann tensor are:
> $$ R^{\mu}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu \gamma \delta} =: \partial_{\gamma} \Gamma^{\mu}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu \delta} + \Gamma^{\xi}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu \delta} \Gamma^{\mu}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\xi \gamma} - \Big(\partial_{\delta} \Gamma^{\mu}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu \gamma} + \Gamma^{\xi}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu \gamma} \Gamma^{\mu}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\xi \delta}\Big)$$
> The covariant derivative components of a (p,q)-tensor are
> $$\nabla_{\mu} T^{\delta_{1}...\delta_{p}}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu_{1}...\nu_{q}} =: \partial_{\mu}T^{\delta_{1}...\delta_{p}}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu_{1}...\nu_{q}} +\Big\{  \Gamma^{\delta_{1}}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\mu \alpha}T^{\alpha ... \delta_{p}}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu_{1}...\nu_{q}}+...+\Gamma^{\delta_{p}}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\mu \alpha}T^{\delta_{1} ... \alpha}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu_{1}...\nu_{q}}         \Big\} - \Big\{ \Gamma^{\alpha}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\mu \nu_{1}}T^{\delta_{1} ... \delta_{p}}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\alpha...\nu_{q}}+...+\Gamma^{\alpha}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\mu \nu_{q}}T^{\delta_{1} ... \delta_{p}}\hspace{0.5mm}_{\nu_{1}...\alpha}                  \Big\}$$

But keeping the standard procedure, which means: given a metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$ we calculate the Christoffel Symbols, then Covariant derivatives, Riemann tensor and so on, sometimes the calculations become quite long and "difficult".
Another method is fruitful, and is called Orthonormal Basis (Tetrad) Method (See Wald.R., *General Relativity*, page 50).

In Wald's book we encounter one definition about *Ricci Rotation Coeficients*:

> $$\omega_{\lambda \mu \nu}= (e_{\lambda})^{a}(e_{\mu})^{b}\nabla_{a}(e_{\nu})_{b} \tag{1}$$

Where the quantities $(e_{\lambda})^{a}$ are the orthonormal basis vector fields called *tetrads*.

But, in the book "Relativity:Demistyfied" we are exposed to another definition:

> The main thrust of this technique is given a set of basis one  forms $\omega^{\hat{b}}$ we wish to calculate the derivatives $d\omega^{\hat{b}}$. These quantities satisfy *Cartan's first structure equation*:
>
> $$d\omega^{\hat{b}} =\displaystyle -\Gamma^{\hat{a}}\hspace{1mm}_{\hat{b}}\wedge\omega^{\hat{b}}$$
> The coeficients $\Gamma^{\hat{a}}\hspace{1mm}_{\hat{b}}$ are called *Ricci Rotation Coeficients*. They are written in terms of basis one forms as follows:
>
> $$\Gamma^{\hat{a}}\hspace{1mm}_{\hat{b}}=\Gamma^{\hat{a}}\hspace{1mm}_{\hat{b}\hat{c}}\omega^{\hat{c}}\tag{2}$$
> Where the $\Gamma^{\hat{a}}\hspace{1mm}_{\hat{b}\hat{c}}$ are the Christoffel Symbols in non-coordinate basis

My question is, what is the precise relation between $(1)$ and $(2)$?.

Comment: Can you give us some context? Is $e$ a frame field or something?

Comment: @BenCrowell I hope that my edits are sufficient now.